# Is there anyway command to round off the numbers in list of the entire Jupyter notebook globally with out using numpy or pandas

Tags: python, list, arraylist

I am searching for a command to round of the entire output of arrays of list with out using numpy or Pandas. Is there any way to do that.

Comment: Why without numpy? What is your data?

Comment: i am trying to invert a matrix and i want the final matrix to have numbers rounded off to  two decimal places.

Comment: then it would by ideal to use numpy, why don't you want to?

Comment: its a task given by our tutor, to not to do row operations with numpy. Is there any code available from other libraries except numpy and pandas

Comment: You have to say it explicitly in the question when it is an assignment. Then the policy is for **you** to provide initial code, not us to do the assignment for you ;) what have you tried?

Comment: wrote the entire code to find inverse of n*n matrix using gauss elimination method. I just needed the final code to round the numbers. Is it necessary to display my noob codes out here( its probably 80-90 lines long)

Comment: The code for inverting, no, the one for rounding yes, would be great

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you’re looking for?

```
list(map(round, my_list))
```

**EDIT:**

Either of these code excerpts would round off all the numbers in a single list, by mapping the `round` function to all of the elements in the list they return:

```
def round_list(my_list):
    return list(map(round, my_list))
```

```
[round(e) for e in my_list]
```

So what if you repeated the pattern of either of those excerpts, mapping one of the above excerpts to every list in your list of lists?

Comment: No dude, its a list of arrays i mean with list in list like this 

 [[0.1794871794871795, -0.45299145299145294, -0.07692307692307693], [0.0, 0.3333333333333333, 0.0], [-0.02564102564102564, 0.01709401709401709, 0.15384615384615385]] 

Upon using your code it throws the error ..type list doesn't define __round__ method

Comment: Ah, thanks for the example. I updated my answer to provide some guidance as to how you might extend it that one step further